# Grails easygrid plugin, Datatable implementation

Tags: grails, datatable, grails-plugin

I'm playing with the datatable implementation in the Easygrid plugin and I have to say i love it but I have a question . If i use datatable directly (ie outside of Easygrid) to decorate a table i get a global search box defined above my table . If i use the Easygrid implementation and define my grid in a controller I get filters added for each column but no search box - it is added but then removed somehow either by easygrid itself or some parameter passed to datatable . How can I  restore the search box and is this a bug as i would have thought the default implementation of datatable supplied via easygrid should match the default implementation supplied by the vanilla datatable itself? I'm using Grails 2.3.7 and Easygrid 1.6.2 ..  Thanks

Comment: Found the code to remove the search box and removing it makes the box appear as expected but entering search criteria doesn't filter the table. Any idea how to re-enable this functionality ?

Comment: And found that using the globalFilterClosure seems to do the trick  ..

Answer (score 0):

see [Issue 78](https://github.com/tudor-malene/Easygrid/issues/78).

In the next version of easygrid, you should be able to enable the standard datatables filter behavior using a flag.

Comment: Thats great .. One final question - i'm trying to wrap it in bootstrap using datatable-bootstrap and while it mostly works again the appearances are slightly different. I noticed easygrid uses datatables 1.9 , are there plans to upgrade to 1.10 ?

Comment: Yes, definitely. On each important easygrid release I also upgrade the javascript dependencies.